# Interactive IDE in a VPAID banner

Tags: javascript, ide, banner, vast

do you think it is possible to integrate a script that create an interactive IDE inside a standard VPAID banner?

I understand there are security limits for distributing banners.

Comment: Could you please specify the IDE you are talking about? I guess the limits are more related to the browser. The VPAID-JS, can be anything.

Comment: @zyexal Thanks. I'd like to give to the user the possibility of writing code and highlight it in different languages (php, python, java)